# Short (6 bit) cryptographic keyed hash

Tags: encryption, cryptography, hash

I have to implement a simple hashing algorithm.

Input data:

- Value (16-bit integer).
- Key (any length).

Output data:

- **6-bit** hash (number 0-63).

Requirements:

- It should be **practically impossible to predict hash value if you only have the input value but not the key**. More specific: if I known hash(x) for x < M, it should be hard to predict hash(M) without knowing the key.

Possible solutions:

1. Keep full mapping as a key. So the key has length 2^16*6 bits. It's too long for my case.
2. Linear code. Key is a generator matrix. It's length is 16*6. But it's easy to find generator matrix using several known hash values.

Are there any other possibilities?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) seems to be what you want. So a possibility for you could be to use a SHA-based HMAC and just use a substring of the resulting hash. This should be relatively safe, since the bits of a cryptographic hash should be as independent and unpredictable as possible.

Depending on your environment, this could however take too much processing time, so you might have to chose a simpler hashing scheme to construct your HMAC.

**Original Answer the discussion in the comments is based on:**

Since you can forget cryptographic properties anyway (it is trivial to find collisions via bruteforce attacks on a 5-bit hash) you might as well use something like CRC or Hamming Codes and get error-detection for free

Comment: CRCs are not hashes. The OP doesn't say what he wants it for, but there are situations in which a CRC is a particularly poor substitute for a hash - such as in a hashtable.

Comment: @NickJohnson why should CRC not be suitable for a hashtable (except that there are faster methods to get a suitable hash)?

Comment: Because as you yourself pointed out, CRCs include redundancy to provide for reliable error detection, which affects their distribution characteristics.

Comment: My information theory lecture is a while back but shouldn't error correcting codes have similar properties like hashes in that changes in the data lead to big changes in the code, except that collisions are trivial to find?

Comment: The only property a CRC guarantees is that changes of fewer than n bitflips result in a different hash. They don't guarantee anything about their clustering properties or how they behave with regards to changes of more bits than that.

Comment: @NickJohnson since CRC is basically the remainder of a polynomial division, there should be no clustering. Wikipedia even mentions that CRC is occasionally used as a hash. I'm not really fit in number theory but I still think we can't simply dismiss CRC as a hash (as long as you do not require collision resistance of course)

Comment: @mensi, thanks for your answer. My question was not detailed enough. I've corrected the description.
The main requirement for the algorithm: it should be practically impossible to predict hash value for a given input value. If I known hash(X) for X < M, it should be hard to predict hash(M) without knowing the key.

Comment: @alexey I adjusted the answer, however it is difficult to tell what your requirements are. Is this an embedded system? Is it for a netowrk protocol?

Answer (score 0):

Mensi' suggestion to use truncated [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) is a good one, but if you do happen to be on a highly constrained system and want something faster or simpler, you could take any [block cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher), encrypt your 16-bit value (padded to a full block) with it and truncate the result to 6 bits.

Unlike HMAC, which computes a [pseudorandom function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_function), a block cipher is a [pseudorandom permutation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_permutation) — every input maps to a different output.  However, when you throw away all but six bits of the block cipher's output, what remains will look very much like a pseudorandom function.  There will be a *very* tiny bias against repeated outputs, but (assuming that the block cipher's block size is much larger than 6 bits, which it should be) it'll be so small as to be all but undetectable.

A good block cipher choice for very low-end systems might be [TEA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_Encryption_Algorithm) or its successors [XTEA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XTEA) and [XXTEA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XXTEA).  While there are some known attacks on these ciphers, they all require much more extensive access to the cipher than should be possible in your application.